Update-Database failed : an error occurred using the connection to database '' on server '' in MySql - Blazor .NET9
In my Blazor web app on .NET 9, when I'm doing the Update-Database for my MySql database v8.4.3, I get this error:

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server ''

Does the message mean that the IP address and database name are missing? Because the error message does not indicate the database name and IP address.
Here are the packages I've installed:
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="9.0.0">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="9.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="8.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>

This is the appsettings.json file:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=x.x.x.x;Port=3306;Database=DB_Cours;User=UserCours;Password=12345678";Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
},


There are numerous questions about connection issues during migrations, please try to find out if your issue is among them. The most common error is not pointing to the right project.

@GertArnold, Thank you so much to try to help me. Can you tell me if the fact that the server and database are not stipulated in the error message doesn't mean that the connection attempt wasn't made with the correct information?

You probably need to wait for the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 9.0.0 which plan to release at January 2025. https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?tab=readme-ov-file#schedule-and-roadmap.
Or try install the preview version by manualy dotnet add package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql --version 9.0.0-preview.2.efcore.9.0.0.
The connection string is like
UseMySql("server=xxx;database=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx", new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8,4,3))


Yes, you can only do this with 9.0.0-preview.2.efcore.9.0.0 . The strangest thing I've found is that it works fine in the same project, but if you apply it in a "clean architecture", it doesn't work.
